# Want to give Ubuntu 18.04 more disk space -- dual XP boot

Tags: disk-usage

I looked at that "Disks" tool, and my main linux partition (26 GB - partition 8) and then Partition 6 (3.7 GB - Linux Swap).  I need to give Linux more space, isn't there a simple way to merge that space?
Is Linux using that swap space?
How can I figure out where to expand it to so it doesn't take over my XP space?
I don't know if I know enough to ask a more succinct question.
Thanks for your patience.[image]

Comment: Well, certainly most Linux uses the SWAP partition (they can work without it, but you may find your OS stopping functioning correctly), even more, I imagine that your machine, if has windows XP, must be old. ¿Can you post an image of your disk partitions layout? Use **gparted** or **Disks**. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1166149/edit) your anwser using the *image tool*, don't post it on a third party website.

Comment: The OS is old but the computer is a new motherboard.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not use a swap partition by default, but can be configured to use it. Normally it will use a swap file. The command `swapon` will tell you what kind of swap that your Ubuntu is using. Would you consider taking part of parttion 1 or 5 for Ubuntu (for example as a separate `/home` partition? Or are you only considering the swap partition (nr 8)? In any case, editing partitions is risky, so you should have a good and current **backup** of everything you cannot afford to lose before starting on this adventure.

Comment: Do you have unallocated space on the 1TB Hard Disk. You could just create a new partition there and mount in Ubuntu and use without messing with existing partitions.

Comment: I wish I knew how to add a picture to this comment but I looked at that 1TB drive and it has 333 GB partition that isn't listed in the "files/other locations"  but when you select it in "disks" it says it is a linux swap partition.  How can I get ubuntu to use it?   swapon says it is using /swapfile 1.1 G.  I'd like linux to start using that huge partition on the 1TB drive

Comment: 333 GB swap partition is kinda overkill :)

Comment: @guillermochamorro yeah, that huge swap partition is almost as absurd as using XP in 2019.

Comment: I could only use part of that partition.  I don't know how to do either and to have Linux use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options (IMHO), some more advanced than others:

> **Backup your data!!**, as @sudodus commented *"In any case, editing partitions is risky, so you should have a good and current backup of everything you cannot afford to lose before starting on this adventure"*

1. Get rid of windows xp (do you really need it?), wipe your disk, and make a fresh install of Ubuntu in your HDD.
2. Format your second NTFS partition, which is larger, to EXT format, and mount `/home` in it.
3. Use your second NTFS partition, and make a fresh install of Ubuntu in it. Merge the last partitions, (except the FAT one, which may be aercovery partitin used by windows?) in the format you prefer.
4. Wipe your disk and install windows 7/10, given that you have modern hardware, and then install Ubuntu alongside it.
5. Other options available depends on what you actually need from your systems.

> You can always make a backup image of your disk with clone tools like
>   [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), so you can retrieve your system to it's previous state.

*And you can always come back here to ask new questions.*

Comment: I'd like to get rid of XP, but have to figure out how to get all my emails and addresses from Thunderbird and onto Linux.  I tried how T-bird said to do it and their directions weren't correct.

Comment: Another question if that's OK or should I make a separate question out of it?

Comment: I had only been saving files to the Linux partition, but realized I can put files on my other drives.  BUT, the problem is that even if I set the permissions on the folder on one of those other drives, I can't see it from the other win7 computer over the network.  What I have to do is copy the file from the other drive  on Linux to the folder on the linux partition that I have shared and then I can access it on the other computer.  Any way to set the permissions on the NTFS folder so that it can be accessed from the other computer?